# PHP Include not working - php too complex?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm just branching my way out into php as I want to have a central menu file that I can edit instead of having to change the code on 20+ pages each time I update it! However my php include does not seem to be working. I'm wondering if maybe my php file I'm trying to include is too complex or doesn't work how I'm thinking (my understanding is that the php include basically takes all the text within it (in this case the html) and replaces the php include line with it)? There is also some css that would format the html when it was actually in the webpage, and I'm wondering if that is what is breaking it? Code is below.

html:

```
<div id="buttonstrip">
<?php include 'menubar.php';?>
</div>
```

php:

```
<?php
echo '<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="computing.html">Computing</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="computingforindividuals.html">For Individuals</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="computerrepair.html">Repair</a></li>
            <li><a href="computermaintenance.html">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="computernewbuilds.html">New Builds</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingtuiton.html">Tuition</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="computingforbusiness.html">For Business</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="computingappraisals.html">Appraisals</a></li>
            <li><a href="computerinstallation.html">Installation</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingmaintenanceforbusiness.html">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingupgrades.html">Upgrades</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="branding.html">Branding</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="brandingandlogos.html">Logos & Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="brandingstationary.html">Stationary</a></li>
        <li><a href="brandingguidelines.html">Guidelines</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="webdesign.html">Web Design</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="webdesignindividuals.html">For Individuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="webdesignbusiness.html">For Business</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="graphicdesign.html">Graphic Design</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="graphicillustration.html">Illustration</a></li>
        <li><a href="graphiprintwork.html">Printwork</a></li>
        <li><a href="graphicmerchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>';
?>
```

CSS

```
nav ul {
/* [disabled]box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); */
padding: 10px 30px;
/* [disabled]border-radius: 10px; */
list-style: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
background-color: #1c6130;
background-position: top;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
color: #1c6130;
    }

nav ul li a {
display: inline;
padding: 20px 40px;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #ffffff; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    /* border-top: 1px solid #6b727c; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; */
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 0px 30px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Apologies if this is a completely novice question.

Comment: Ummm.. what? You have an *entire* PHP file (*with no PHP*) and *all* you do is output HTML (*again; you don't use PHP at all*) *through an echo command*? (*if it's not in PHP tags it'll just get output automatically.*) Why not just have an HTML file? Use `echo file_get_contents('file.html')` to read it.

Comment: Any errors displayed?

Comment: Is the first _HTML_ file an actual HTML file or PHP? If you want to use PHP code your file needs to have a .php extension (or you need to tell your server to handle a file as PHP)

Comment: the file that has the include in, is a PHP file right ?

Comment: h2ooooooo is right. If you just write the html outside the <?php ?> tags, it will output that. 
About the include not working, how are you saving the first file? you should save it as .php unless your server is configured to treat .html files as php files. Another thing: are you trying this on a server or are you opening the file with the browser (the second won't work).

Comment: You're all very right on all counts. I am feeling very 'special' right now. I was at least trying it on a server however, but did not realise that you couldn't just put a line of php into a html file. i have now changed the filename of the html file to be .php, and it all works perfectly.

Comment: The first file should be php. 
and in the second file, remove closing PHP tag ( ?> ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: Your "html" file is actually named `something.html`, which causes the webserver to not recognize it as PHP. Rename it into `something.php`.

To verify that this was the problem, check the source of your HTML page, you should see the literal PHP code displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you misnamed any file. just follow the instruction and keep all files in the same folder

**File-index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>My index page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="buttonstrip">
<?php include 'menubar.php';?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Menu file-menu.php**

```
<?php
echo '<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="computing.html">Computing</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="computingforindividuals.html">For Individuals</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="computerrepair.html">Repair</a></li>
            <li><a href="computermaintenance.html">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="computernewbuilds.html">New Builds</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingtuiton.html">Tuition</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="computingforbusiness.html">For Business</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="computingappraisals.html">Appraisals</a></li>
            <li><a href="computerinstallation.html">Installation</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingmaintenanceforbusiness.html">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="computingupgrades.html">Upgrades</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="branding.html">Branding</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="brandingandlogos.html">Logos & Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="brandingstationary.html">Stationary</a></li>
        <li><a href="brandingguidelines.html">Guidelines</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="webdesign.html">Web Design</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="webdesignindividuals.html">For Individuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="webdesignbusiness.html">For Business</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="graphicdesign.html">Graphic Design</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="graphicillustration.html">Illustration</a></li>
        <li><a href="graphiprintwork.html">Printwork</a></li>
        <li><a href="graphicmerchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>';
?>
```

**Menu css->menu.css**

```
nav ul {
/* [disabled]box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); */
padding: 10px 30px;
/* [disabled]border-radius: 10px; */
list-style: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
background-color: #1c6130;
background-position: top;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
color: #1c6130;
    }

nav ul li a {
display: inline;
padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="buttonstrip">
<?php include ('menubar.php');?>
</div>
```

This appears correct. Only thing to check is the path of your include file.
Make sure your menubar.php is indeed located on the same folder as your script that includes it.
Make sure there are no spelling errors also on file name.

Answer (score -2):

Create a menu.php file and include this file in php page where you want to show menu.
To include menu file in php file use     `<?php include "menu.php"; ?>`

Below code is for menu.php

```
   <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="insert.php">Insert</a></li> 
            <li><a href="update.php">Update</a></li> 
            <li><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></li> 
            <li><a href="display.php">Display</a></li>
    <li><a href="gui.php">GUI</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: OP already has this code. You aren't really helping.